# 2001 Crown Victoria alternator exiter wire

Tags: ford, alternator, crown-victoria

My 2001 Crown Victoria appears to have a short somewhere in the harness which is going to be hard to find.

As a temporary fix - can I connect the alternator exister straight to the battery? Is it okay that is going to be more than 12v.

Also, where does the exiter wire come from - so I can troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your wiring diagram, not it is not a good idea to connect to the battery directly as it will drain the battery overnight. Check the fuse, it may be blown

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the diagram. Is the alternator fuse same as the starter fuse. I had removed it because it kept blowing.

Comment: Not sure, it is fuse 14 in the central junction box, 10 amps.